# Let $f$ be defined on $[a,b]$ s.t. $b$ is a minimum and $f$ is differentiable at $b$. Prove or disprove: $f'(b)\le 0.$

Tags: derivatives, continuity

> Let $f$ be a function that is defined on $[a,b]$ such that $b$ is a minimum. Assume also that $f$ is differentiable at $b$. Prove or disprove:
>
> $$f'(b) \le 0 $$

I want to prove it is true, as $f$ is differentiable at $b$ and $b$ is a minimum so from fermat's theorem $f'(b) = 0$ and therefore $f'(b) \le 0 $. I want to make sure if my reasoning is correct or if I am missing something.

Comment: What is fermat's theorem?

Comment: The interior extremum theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)

Comment: Fermat does not apply to endpoints.

Comment: Thanks a lot had a feeling I am missing something

Comment: You may try to revisit the proof of Fermat's theorem, and found that one indeed have $f'\le 0$ in this case. (when the minimum is attained at the right end point)

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles

Comment: Use the fact that $\forall x\in [a,b) \frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}\le 0$

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed out by hamam_Abdallah in the comments,

$\ b\ $ is a minimum and so $\ \forall\ x\in\ [a,b),\ \frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}\leq 0.$

By assumption, $\ f\ $ is differentiable at $\ b,\ $ and so $\ \lim_{x\to b^-} \frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}\ $ exists.

But the limit of numbers $\ \leq 0\ $ must be $\ \leq\ 0,\ $ hence the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Since $b$ is a minimum, you have $f(b)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Thus for all $a\leq x<b$ we have
$$\frac{f(x) - f(b)}{x-b} \leq 0. $$
Take the limit when $x\to b$, and you obtain $f'(b) \leq 0$.